# How to solve this puzzle in Prolog? (robbery)

Tags: prolog, logic, constraint-satisfaction

Three suspects are involved in a robbery, Alice, Bob, Carl. At least one of them are guilty.

Here are the conditions:

If A is guilty, he has exactly 1 accomplice.

If B is guilty, he has exactly 2 accomplices.

Who are guilty?

How can I write a `Prolog` script to solve this problem which `guilty(X)` gives the gangs?

Comment: You should take a look a library clpb of SWI-Prolog

Comment: Only A and C are guilty, I want to know how to program the facts into Prolog and let the computer to do the inference.

Comment: It's a long while (20 years) since I wrote any prolog code, but I would have thought one way to go about it would be to write predicates that express the fact that two of the suspects are guilty but not three of them.  Btw is A only supposed to stand for Alice?

Comment: yes, A stands for Alice, B stands for Bob and C stands for Carl

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using clpb :

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

solve(A,B,C) :-
 % there is a least one guilty
 sat(A + B + C),
 % If A is guilty, he has exactly 1 accomplice.
 sat(A =< B # C),
 % if B is guilty, he has exactly 2 accomplices.
 sat(B =< A * C),
 % Assigns truth values to the variables such that all constraints are satisfied.
 labeling([A,B,C]).
```

Now we get :

```
?- solve(A,B,C).
A = B, B = 0,
C = 1 ;
A = C, C = 1,
B = 0.
```

The answer A = B, B = 0, C = 1 means that C is guilty the other one that A and C are guilties.

Answer (score 0):

Let's encode the state of our world as three numbers, A, B, and C.

Each number will be either *1* (guilty) or *0* (innocent).

The conditions are:

```
at_least_one(A,B,C):- 0 < A+B+C.

one_accomplice(A,B,C):- A == 1 -> 1 is ....... ; true.

two_accomplices(A,B,C):- B == 1 -> ....... ; true.
```

The three rules holding together is

```
ok(A,B,C):- at_least_one(A,B,C), 
            one_accomplice(A,B,C), 
            ...... .
```

Now we can find out the gangs, as

```
the_guilty([A,B,C]):-
  ( A = 0 ; A = 1 ),
  ....
  ....
  ok( ..... ).
```

The last thing  is to report the three given numbers as names of people. We *know* that the first number is for `"Alice"`, the second is for `"Bob"`, etc.

Prolog is *easy*.