# Solving a logic task using Prolog

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I started to learn Prolog and I can't solve a difficult task for me.

On Halloween, three friends - Bob, Mark, Alex, chose the costumes of three ghosts: a ghost, a zombie, a werewolf. It is known that:

- Bob is the tallest.
- The one who chose the werewolf costume is shorter than the one who chose the ghost costume.
- Alex didn't fit the werewolf costume.
- None of the friends have the same name as the Halloween character from the selected costumes.

Which costume did each of the friends choose?

I solved the problem mathematically, but it is impossible to describe its solution in Prolog.

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804159/how-to-solve-this-puzzle-in-prolog-robbery/46868352#46868352.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(the previous versions of this answer suffered from the "premature implementation syndrome". Here's another take on it)*

> I started to learn Prolog and I can't solve a difficult task for me. [...] it is impossible to describe its solution in Prolog.

Nah! :) If we can say it in English we can say it in Prolog:

```
task( Sol) :-
```

> On Halloween, three friends - *Bob*, *Mark*, *Alex*, chose the *costumes* of three ghosts: a *ghost*, a *zombie*, a *werewolf*.

```
    Sol = [bob-C1, mark-C2, alex-C3],
    permutation( [ghost, zombie, werewolf], [C1,C2,C3]),
```

> It is known that:
>
> - *Bob* is the *tallest*.

```
    select( bob-_, Sol, ShorterOnes),
```

> - The one who chose the *werewolf* costume is *shorter* than the one who chose the *ghost* costume.

```
    member( _-werewolf, ShorterOnes),
```

> - *Alex* didn't fit the *werewolf* costume.

```
    C3 \= werewolf,
```

> - *None* of the friends have the *same name* as the Halloween character from the selected costumes.
>
>   Apparently, there is one Bob the Ghost, so

```
    C1 \= ghost,
```

> Which costume did each of the friends choose?

```
    true.  % nothing more to say
```

So we *were* able to describe the problem in Prolog, after all.

Having described the problem properly, we already have our program to find the solution.

Testing:

```
13 ?- task(X).
X = [bob-zombie, mark-werewolf, alex-ghost] ;
false.
```

---

This can be written a tiny bit shorter if we realize that selecting `bob` as the tallest

```
    select( bob-_, Sol, ShorterOnes),
    member( _-werewolf, ShorterOnes),
```

leaves us with `mark` and `alex` as the shorter ones:

```
task( [bob-C1, mark-C2, alex-C3]) :-
    permutation( [ghost, zombie, werewolf], [C1,C2,C3]),
    member( werewolf, [C2, C3]),
    C3 \= werewolf,
    C1 \= ghost.
```

Glancing at *this* short code for a minute, we realize that it can be further simplified to

```
task( [bob-C1, mark-C2, alex-C3]) :-
    permutation( [ghost, zombie, werewolf], [C1,C2,C3]),
    ( werewolf = C2 ; werewolf = C3 ),
    C3 \= werewolf,
    C1 \= ghost.
```

and this to

```
task( [bob-C1, mark-C2, alex-C3]) :-
    permutation( [ghost, zombie, werewolf], [C1,C2,C3]),
    werewolf = C2,
    C1 \= ghost.
```

and this to

```
task( [bob-C1, mark-werewolf, alex-C3]) :-
    permutation( [ghost, zombie], [C1,C3]),
    C1 \= ghost.
```

and this to

```
task( [bob-zombie, mark-werewolf, alex-ghost]).
```

And this version we don't even need to run.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using clpb .

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).


solve :-
    /* Alex is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Alex * GhostA , Alex * ZombieA , Alex * WerewolfA])),

    /* Bob is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Bob * GhostB , Bob * ZombieB , Bob * WerewolfB])),

    /* Mark is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Mark * GhostM , Mark * ZombieM , Mark * WerewolfM])),

    /* Alex wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA])),

    /* Bob wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB])),

    /* Mark wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM])),

    /* There is only one ghost costume */
    sat(card([1], [GhostA,    GhostB,    GhostM])),

    /* There is only one zombie costume */
    sat(card([1], [ZombieA,   ZombieB,   ZombieM])),

    /* There is only one werewolf costume */
    sat(card([1], [WerewolfA, WerewolfB, WerewolfM])),

    /* Alex didn't fit the werewolf costume. */
    sat(Alex * ~WerewolfA),

    /*  Bob can't wear the ghost costume. */
    sat(Bob * ~GhostB),

    /* Bob is the tallest */
    sat(BobHigherA * ~AlexHigherB),
    sat(BobHigherM * ~MarkHigherB),

    /* For Alex and Mark we don't know */
    sat(AlexHigherM * ~MarkHigherA + ~AlexHigherM * MarkHigherA ),

    /* The one who chose the werewolf costume is shorter than the one who chose the ghost costume. */
    sat((WerewolfB * GhostA) =< (BobHigherA  < AlexHigherB)),
    sat((WerewolfB * GhostM) =< (BobHigherM  < MarkHigherB)),
    sat((WerewolfA * GhostB) =< (AlexHigherB < BobHigherA)),
    sat((WerewolfA * GhostM) =< (AlexHigherM < MarkHigherA)),
    sat((WerewolfM * GhostB) =< (MarkHigherB < BobHigherM)),
    sat((WerewolfM * GhostA) =< (MarkHigherA < AlexHigherM)),

    /* We solve the puzzle */
    labeling([GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA, GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB, GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM]),

    writef('Alex => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA]),
    writef('Bob  => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB]),
    writef('Mark => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM]).
```

The answer is

```
?- solve.
Alex => Ghost 1 Zombie 0 Werewolf 0
Bob  => Ghost 0 Zombie 1 Werewolf 0
Mark => Ghost 0 Zombie 0 Werewolf 1
true.
```

[EDIT] After a search on the internet, I found these Halloween characters: Bob the ghost, Alex the werewolf and Mark the Zombie. So there is no need of the fact that "Alex didn't fit the werewolf costume."

We get now :

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

solve :-
    /* Alex is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Alex * GhostA , Alex * ZombieA , Alex * WerewolfA])),

    /* Bob is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Bob * GhostB , Bob * ZombieB , Bob * WerewolfB])),

    /* Mark is wearing one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [Mark * GhostM , Mark * ZombieM , Mark * WerewolfM])),

    /* Alex wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA])),

    /* Bob wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB])),

    /* Mark wears only one of the following costumes */
    sat(card([1], [GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM])),

    /* There is only one ghost costume */
    sat(card([1], [GhostA,    GhostB,    GhostM])),

    /* There is only one zombie costume */
    sat(card([1], [ZombieA,   ZombieB,   ZombieM])),

    /* There is only one werewolf costume */
    sat(card([1], [WerewolfA, WerewolfB, WerewolfM])),

    /*  Alex can't wear the zombie costume. */
    sat(Alex * ~ZombieA),

    /*  Bob can't wear the ghost costume. */
    sat(Bob * ~GhostB),

    /*  Mark can't wear the werewolf costume. */
    sat(Mark * ~WerewolfM),

    /* Bob is the tallest */
    sat(BobHigherAlex * ~AlexHigherBob),
    sat(BobHigherMark * ~MarkHigherBob),

    /* For Alex and Mark we don't know */
    sat(AlexHigherMark * ~MarkHigherAlex + ~AlexHigherMark * MarkHigherAlex ),

    /* The one who chose the werewolf costume is shorter than the one who chose the ghost costume. */
    sat((WerewolfB * GhostA) =< (BobHigherAlex  < AlexHigherBob)),
    sat((WerewolfB * GhostM) =< (BobHigherMark  < MarkHigherBob)),
    sat((WerewolfA * GhostB) =< (AlexHigherBob < BobHigherAlex)),
    sat((WerewolfA * GhostM) =< (AlexHigherMark < MarkHigherAlex)),
    sat((WerewolfM * GhostB) =< (MarkHigherBob < BobHigherMark)),
    sat((WerewolfM * GhostA) =< (MarkHigherAlex < AlexHigherMark)),

    /* We solve the puzzle */
    labeling([GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA, GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB, GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM]),

    writef('Alex => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostA, ZombieA, WerewolfA]),
    writef('Bob  => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostB, ZombieB, WerewolfB]),
    writef('Mark => Ghost %d Zombie %d Werewolf %d\n', [GhostM, ZombieM, WerewolfM]).
```

And the solution is now

```
?- solve.
Alex => Ghost 0 Zombie 0 Werewolf 1
Bob  => Ghost 0 Zombie 1 Werewolf 0
Mark => Ghost 1 Zombie 0 Werewolf 0
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dif`:

```
go(Sol) :-
    Sol = [bob-Bob, mark-Mark, alex-Alex],

    % werewolf is not tallest (Bob)
    dif(Bob, werewolf),

    dif(Alex, werewolf),

    % Not usual names
    dif(Bob, ghost),

    permutation([Bob, Mark, Alex], [ghost, zombie, werewolf]).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- go(Sol).
Sol = [bob-zombie, mark-werewolf, alex-ghost] ;
false.
```